# Calling a method from the constructor in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is it possible to call a method from the constructor in Coffeescript?
e.g.

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->
    move()

  move: (meters) ->
    alert @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Snake extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Slithering..."
    super 5

sam = new Snake "Sammy the Python"
```

This is generating the following error message "ReferenceError: move is not defined"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is possible. However, to refer to the method you must use `@move()` or `this.move()`, the name `move()` itself is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

Gotcha Alert: if you find that @ or this does NOT refer to the new instance in a constructor, check you remembered to use the NEW keyword:

```
instance = new Class()
```

NOT:

```
instance = Class()
```

This caught me out and was really frustrating. Hope this helps someone else!